# Swift Generic Function Types Ordering

Tags: swift, function, generics, parameters

Assume that I have:

```
protocol A {
    ...
}
```

```
protocol B: A {
    ... // some associated types
}
```

```
struct C: B {
    ...
}
```

I want to make a function `foo(of:)` that separates the actions for different types. Like:

```
func foo<AHolder: A>(of: AHolder) { ... }

func foo<BHolder: B>(of: BHolder) { ... }

func foo(of: C) { ... }
```

However, all callings of `foo(of:)` are going into the case of `foo<AHolder: A>(of: AHolder)` instead of their corresponding types, even though `type(of:)` function returns a `C` for the parameter.

I have tried to use `in` statement to separate the types but `in` does not compile for protocols when their associated types remain unknown (which is the `B` case showing above).

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: How exactly you are passing the type? Note that generics are statically typed, not dynamically typed, therefore the method to call is decided during compilation and it depends on how the given variable is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the type information **at the call site**, consider this two structs :

```
struct AHolder: A {
    
}
struct BHolder: B {
    
}
```

and let's say that your `foo` methods only print:

```
func foo<AHolder: A>(of: AHolder) {
    print("AHolder")
}

func foo<BHolder: B>(of: BHolder) {
    print("BHolder")
}

func foo(of: C) {
    print("C")
}
```

this works fine :

```
foo(of: C()) // prints "C"
foo(of: AHolder()) // prints "AHolder"
foo(of: BHolder()) // prints "BHolder"
```

Why? because **at the call site** the compiler knows that you want to print an instance of `C`, an instance of `AHolder` and an instance of `BHolder`.

now try this :

```
let a: some A = BHolder()
foo(of: a) // prints "AHolder"
let b: some B = C()
foo(of: b) // prints "BHolder"
```

**At the call site**, all the compiler knows is that `a` is an object of *some* type conforming to `A`, and b an object of *some* type conforming to `B`, so even if the variables are really instances of `BHolder` and `C`, the compiler does not know that and uses the overloads that match the types it **knows** ie. `foo<AHolder: A>(of:)` and `foo<BHolder: B>(of:)`.